# HOUR formula return incorrect result when the argument contains custom format DateTime value

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, excel-formula

The DateTime.TryParse or DateTime.Parse method does not return a valid input when the input string is 31 Jan 10:01:23.
How to parse the value as Datetime.

For example, i am using the input in Hour formula
=HOUR("31 Jan 10:01:23")

Comment: That isn't really a date and time - it doesn't contain a year. What would you expect the value to be? Separately, it's entirely unclear whether you're *actually* parsing the string as a `DateTime`, or trying to use it in an Excel formula. I suggest you focus on *one* of those.

Comment: With a little cheat: https://dotnetfiddle.net/3EwYGv

Comment: First you need to make sure that your strings are formatted correctly for the method you are using.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your request but if you want a cell to display data and time, you put the date in a cell (example D4 with the formula =date(year, month, days) and you put the time in another cell (example B4 with the formula =time(hour, minutes ,seconds) and then in the cell where you want to display them use the formula =D4+B4